# Callback on Durandal Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, durandal

I have a custom [Durandal](http://durandaljs.com/) viewmodel which has the method:

```
customModalNewMetric.show(someid);
```

In my `CustomModalNewMetric` viewmodel, the method looks like this:

```
CustomModalNewMetric.show = function(someid) {
        return dialog.show(new CustomModalNewMetric(someid));
};
```

How can I execute some function after the `dialog.show` function is complete? I want to execute some jQuery after the dialog is shown.

Answer (score 1):

Durandal's [`dialog.show()`](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/api/#module/dialog/method/show) returns a `promise`, so all you need to do is the following:

```
CustomModalNewMetric.show = function(someid) {
    return dialog.show(new CustomModalNewMetric(someid)).then(function(data) {
    //callback function here (called after dialog is closed)
    //also will return any passed data
    });
}
```

*NOTE:* When using durandal, make sure you have:

- defined all your modules using requirejs
- check for any errors within your console.

***EDIT (12/24/2013):***

I came across [this example](http://dfiddle.github.io/dFiddle-2.0/#modal/dFiddle), with the [source code](https://github.com/dFiddle/dFiddle-2.0/blob/gh-pages/app/masterDetail/dFiddle/project.js) that illustrates the answer I provided.

Let me know if you have any other questions!

Answer (score 0):

To perform subsequent commands **after the dialog has opened**, it looks as though what you need to do is to add your own dialog context with a compositionComplete method ([DialogContext.compositionComplete](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/api/#class/DialogContext/method/compositionComplete)).

You can add a new context with the [dialog.addContext](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/api/#module/dialog/method/addContext) method.

Here I am crudely decorating the default context and adding it as `'myContext'` (there are likely to be more elegant ways of doing this):

```
dialog.addContext('myContext', {

  // Retain the behaviour of the original default context
  parentContext: dialog.getContext(),

  // Nothing but a passthrough to the parent context
  addHost: function(theDialog) {
    this.parentContext.addHost(theDialog);
  },
  removeHost: function(theDialog) {
    this.parentContext.removeHost(theDialog);
  },
  attached: function(view) {
    this.parentContext.attached(view);
  },

  // Here we do something different
  compositionComplete: function(child, parent, context) {
    this.compositionComplete(child, parent, context);
    // Do something now that the modal is open
    console.log('Modal opened');
  }
});
```

Then when you open the dialog you'll need to pass the context name:

```
dialog.show(new CustomModalNewMetric(someid), null, 'myContext');
```